# Domain Setting and IIS setting

Tags: iis, dns

I have an IP address eg 1.2.3.4 and i have a domain name from namecheap eg ABC.COM

in ABC.COM i configure

- @ 1.2.3.4
- A 1.2.3.4

but in IIS setting of my port 80 my site is not configure to use host ABC.COM but it still works, if I configure ABC.COM in the host setting, it won't work. Why?

And how to add a sub domain for example domain1.ABC.COM and point it to a new website in IIS?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ would probably more appropriate place for question on configuring IIS and domains. In any case please clarify "it won't work" - it is very hard to reason what url you've tries and waht results you got.

Comment: This is really about server configuration, not programming. You could try serverfault, but do search there a bit prior to asking as I think this has been covered several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And how to add a sub domain for example domain1.ABC.COM and point it to a new website in IIS?" - add new subdomain in your DNS settings and then create new website in IIS and set it to work on the same IP address you set in the DNS

"but in IIS setting of my port 80 my site is not configure to use host ABC.COM but it still works, if I configure ABC.COM in the host setting, it won't work. Why?" - better try with setting IP address in IIS instead of host name.